# Enumerable Range to increase int by 1

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, wcf

I'm using `Enumerable.Range(1, 1).FirstOrDefault()`to try to increase my `MKCRFQ` number by `1` each time a new row is created in my database/table. I'm using a WCF service and a WPF application.

**Client**:

```
using (MKCServiceClient service = new MKCServiceClient())
{
    await service.GetQuoteAsync(new QuoteData
    {
        ...
        MKCRFQ = Enumerable.Range(1, 1).FirstOrDefault(),
        ...
    });
}
```

**Service**:

```
public QuoteResults CalculateResult(Database db, QuoteData data)
{
    var result = new QuoteResults
    {
        Successful = false,
        Data = data
    };

    var quote = new Quote
    {
        ...
        MKCRFQ = data.MKCRFQ,
        ...
    };

    result.Quote = quote;
    result.Successful = true;
    return result;
}

public void GetQuote(QuoteData data)
{
    using (Database db = new Database())
    {
        var result = CalculateResult(db, data);
        db.Quote.Add(result.Quote);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My issue is that each time I insert a new row of data the `MKCRFQ` number for each new row added is `1`, and I do not know how to increase(+1) it with each new row added. This might seem really simple, but i've never done this before and don't know how. Can someone please explain or show me how this is done?

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(1, 1).FirstOrDefault()`, really? why not 1 directly :)

Comment: Why would you expect `Enumerable.Range(1, 1)` to do what you expect? It will never return anything else than `{ 1 }`, not an incrementing number every time you call it (and especially not after an application restart). If you want to get the maximum number that's currently in your database, then query your database for the maximum number and increase that by one.

Comment: So, if I just use `Enumerable.Range(1)`, I would get the result that I need? 0_o

Comment: No, what makes you think so? Did you try reading [`Enumerable.Range()`'s documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx)? That method does **not** do what you think it does, you'll need to write the code to do what you want to do yourself.

Comment: Yes, but only quickly. I should better get on to reading more then. It's my first time using `Enumerable.Range`, sorry ;P

Comment: write `MKCRFQ++;` to increase it by 1

Comment: @M.kazem and upvoter of that comment: no, that makes no sense. OP wants in the service code that the `MKCRFQ` property of the `new QuoteData` is the value of the currently highest `MKCRFQ`, + 1. As it is a new object, there is nothing to `++`, it will always be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I know this wasn't a good question...but I figured it out by my self. It might not be some of the best coding or full proof, but it works and I'm posting this here for anyone that might need a reference of how I did it :)

This is my service coding where it all happens:

```
public void GetQuote(QuoteData data)
{
    using (Database db = new Database())
    {
        var result = CalculateResult(db, data);

        byte[] pdfByte = (result.Data.PDF);
        var pdf = new PDF { PDFbyte = pdfByte, CustomerId = result.Data.CustomerId };
        db.PDF.Add(pdf);

        //Here
        int rfqLast = (from x in db.Quote where x.MKCRFQ != null orderby x.Id descending select x.MKCRFQ).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
        var rfqAdd = new Quote { MKCRFQ = rfqLast + 1 };

        result.Quote.MKCRFQ = rfqAdd.MKCRFQ;

        db.Quote.Add(result.Quote);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to select a `MAX(MKCRFQ)` instead. That may coincidentally correspond to the `MAX(ID)`, but it's never guaranteed to.